# Magento running on Percona Server with XtraDB

Tags: magento-1, configuration, sql, performance, architecture

Does anyone have any experience with

Magento db running on **[Percona Server with XtraDB?](http://www.percona.com/software/percona-server)**

Benchmarking, stres testing, numbers... anything

Comment: Used it for awhile on a high load (lots of admins logged in) server, I didn't notice a very large difference, other than some tables corrupting on me, so I went back to vanilla MySQL.  For simplicity sake Percona is just a fork of MySQL modified by some MySQL experts.

Answer (score 12):

We use Percona exclusively on all our servers - as it is bundled into the MageStack OS.

In terms of numbers, given that Magento isn't bound by MySQL in the majority of cases, the performance improvement from changing to Percona XtraDB (or even MariaDB) is negligible or non-existent.

You can find a few answers down a similar vein, as to where your efforts are best spent:

https://serverfault.com/questions/263444/which-should-i-put-on-my-bigger-machine-magento-webserver-of-magento-database/367856#367856

The benefits usually stem from being able to take advantage of the additional Percona tools, like hot backup; their consultative support; frequency of releases etc.

#### Why no benchmark ...

As all Magento stores are different, with different catalogues, different customer browsing habits - drawing an accurate conclusion from a test performed (even on a neutral like the demo store) is pointless.

Just because a certain change benefited a given store configuration, doesn't mean it will assist for others.

Answer (score 2):

I briefly tried running it in a test back in the 1.5.X era. I wasn't able to get to performance metrics because I was getting some errors that prevented the site from running. At the time I was too inexperienced to know what was going wrong so I didn't peruse it. I will make a note to test it again this week.

Sorry not a better answer.

I don't recall what version it was at the time of testing either.

Answer (score 2):

We run Percona MySQL on many Magento servers and hosting farms and have found the new versions to handle InnoDB very well.  With version 5.5.29 we've not seen any problems at all.  The servers are stable and the response on Magento hosting farms is excellent.

We switched a long while back and I can't seem to find any Magento specific benchmarks related to our experience however at the MySQL Performance Blog you can get an idea of just how much better Percona is at InnoDB than vanilla MySQL.

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/07/14/performance-improvements-in-percona-5-0-83-and-xtradb/

Updates by the Percona team are 'fast' - Even faster than MySQL at fixing known issues or bugs at times.